# Reinstalling MySQL or Resetting its Root Password

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am running MySQL 5.7.19, under LAMP, on two Ubuntu 16.04.  This is an AWS EC2 instance.

It is some time since I installed MySQL and I have not used it so it would not be a problem if I reinstalled it.  Nothing I enter for the root password works.

I tried

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
sudo  mysql -u root
```

Resulted in

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I then tried the procedure outlined [here](https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/).  When I entered

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic but it is     not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I enter

```
ps -aux | grep mysql
```

the result is

```
ubuntu   27152  0.0  0.0  12948   984 pts/1    S+   12:30   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

When I enter

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

I get

```
Enter password:
```

So mysql has not been uninstalled and I cannot reconfigure it.

Update 1:

When I ran

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

I got

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative 
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf because link group my.cnf is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /etc/mysql/my.cnf with a link
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] unknown option '--~'
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

 mysql -u root -p
```

results in

```
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Edit 2

I tried the following with the associated results.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-73:~$ sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic but it is     not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify     a solution).
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-73:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic but it is     not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify     a solution).
```

Running

```
apt-get -f install
```

did not change anything.

Edit 3:

If I use

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

it take me into mysql.  If I use the -p switch, it accepts anything as a password.  However, when I enter

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newPassword') WHERE User='root';
```

I get

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

Warning (Code 1681): 'PASSWORD' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

I then entered

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and got the following message

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I then quit and  still get the same result if I do not use sudo

```
 mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Edit 4:

I tried the following with the ensuing results.

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-119 but it     is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-73:~$ sudo apt-get -f install linux-headers-4.4.0-119-    generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-119 but it     is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer     required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64 linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-    66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-    72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-    generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-    79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-83 linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87 linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-89 linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-91 linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-92 linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-    4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-119 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-119 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 224 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 78.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 512472 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-119_4.4.0-119.143_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-119 (4.4.0-119.143) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-    119_4.4.0-119.143_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-    119/include/linux/cpufeature.h.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/src/linux-        headers-4.4.0-119/include/linux/cpufeature.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full     error
                                                                                      dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-    119.143_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-    119-generic_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-    generic/include/config/rtc/drv/88pm860x.h.dpkg-new' (while processing     './usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic/include/config/rtc/drv/88pm860x.h'):     No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full     error
                                                                                  dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-119_4.4.0-119.143_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-    119.143_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              498080       0    498080   0% /dev
tmpfs             101440   12068     89372  12% /run
/dev/xvda1       8117828 5515716   2166836  72% /
tmpfs             507184       0    507184   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             507184       0    507184   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             101444       0    101444   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Did you do this: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these`?

Comment: I did try that but it did not resolve the problem.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted it out.

First, found and remove all instances of my.cnf.bak.  Also removed /etc/alternatives/my.cnf, /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/conf.d  (but backed them up).  Then

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

If you still get something like

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

this is often resolved with

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 4):

To reset MySQL passord please follow the procedure from "[B.5.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)":

> Stop the MySQL server by sending a normal `kill` (not `kill -9`) to the
>   `mysqld` process. Use the actual path name of the .pid file in the
>   following command:

```
kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
```

> Use backticks (not forward quotation marks) with the cat command.
>   These cause the output of cat to be substituted into the kill command.
>
> Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a
>   single line. Replace the password with the password that you want to
>   use.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

> Save the file. This example assumes that you name the file
>   `/home/me/mysql-init`. The file contains the password, so do not save it
>   where it can be read by other users. If you are not logged in as `mysq`l
>   (the user the server runs as), make sure that the file has permissions
>   that permit `mysql` to read it.
>
> Start the MySQL server with the special `--init-file` option:

```
mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
```

> The server executes the contents of the file named by the `--init-file`
>   option at startup, changing the `'root'@'localhost'` account password.
>
> Other options may be necessary as well, depending on how you normally
>   start your server. For example, `--defaults-fil`e may be needed before
>   `--init-file`.
>
> After the server has started successfully, delete `/home/me/mysql-init`.

Comment: I installed mysql using the default settings.  Would the mysql data directory be  /var/lib/mysql/?  I did not see any .pid files in that directory.  The only .pid files I could find were in directories under /run.  E.g. /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid.  Thanks,

Comment: Do you have mysql daemon run? If not continue with creation of text tile.

Comment: Would "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop" stop the mysql daemon?  I created /home/ubuntu/mysql-init with the new password, ran "mysqld --init-file=/home/ubuntu/mysql-init &" and then "sudo systemctl restart mysql".  I then tried "mysql -u root -p" and entered the new password.  I got "ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'".  Thanks,

Comment: You can try to login as `root@ip-10-0-1-73` instead of just `root`

Comment: I tried that then accidentally left out the -p switch.  I find when I use sudo (sudo  mysql -u root), with or without the -p switch, it accepts any password.  I then change the password inside mysql.  However, if I leave out the "sudo", it still does not accept the new password.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's fix your package manager problem. Install the missing dependencies using:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

After that, if you had already uninstalled `mysql-server`, please reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

If you didn't uninstall it yet, or if reinstalling it did not prompt you for a new MySQL root password, now run (adapting the version number if necessary):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

That should have reset your password by now. Try logging in again as root with interactive password prompt:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

If you still get the error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

that most likely means that the MySQL server is not running. Try starting it with:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

After that, `systemctl status mysql` should report it as "active(running)". Try logging in again then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately, I am getting the errors shown under Update 1 of my question.  Thanks,

Comment: Okay, that's weird. So you say you don't need any of the data/settings related to the current mysql installation? In that case, I'd suggest trying `sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server` followed by `sudo apt install mysql-server`.

Comment: I have just tried that with the results shown in edit 2.  Thanks,

Comment: Seems my mysql has managed to get corrupted somehow. Is there a way to completely blow it away so I can do a clean install?  Thanks,

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic ; sudo apt upgrade` or something like that, then try my previous comment again.

Comment: The results of trying that are under Edit 4 of the question.  I also have an interesting observation under edit 3.  Thanks,